# How do I add a class to an arraylist in processing?

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

Whenever I try to add a `country` into my `ArrayList<country>`  I keep on getting this error: `unexpected token: (` and it highlights my `countries.add` line. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
class country  {
    private int mland, mwaters; //mtotalborders;
    private String mcenter;

    country(int earth, int aqua, String yn)  {
        mland = earth;
        mwaters = aqua;
        mcenter = yn;
    }
    public int getLand()  {
        return mland;
    }
    public int getWaters()  {
        return mwaters;
    }
    public int getTotalBorders()  {
        return mland+mwaters;
    }
    public String getCenter()  {
        return mcenter;
    }
}

country Turkey = new country(16, 7, "No");
country France = new country(22, 4, "No");
country England = new country(17, 9, "No");
country Germany = new country(26, 4, "Yes");
country Austria = new country(28, 1, "Yes");
country Italy = new country(17, 8, "Yes");
country Russia = new country(23, 3, "No");
ArrayList<country> countries = new ArrayList<country>();
countries.add(Turkey);
```

Comment: Class names should start with a capital and objects shouldn't. Following code style helps you understand other code and helps others read yours. [here's](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) a guide :)

Comment: Class name must start with uppercase character, so, country should be named as Country.

Comment: So do I only capitalize the first country or every time? I capitalized every country and lowercased the country names and still got the same error.

Comment: Using a `String` with two values, "Yes" or "No", is a pretty bad idea. Consider using a `boolean` or perhaps an `enum` instead. This is not related to the problem you're having, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put your code into a method - you probably want to use the `main` method - see below.

```
    ......

    public String getCenter()  {
        return mcenter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        country Turkey = new country(16, 7, "No");
        country France = new country(22, 4, "No");
        country England = new country(17, 9, "No");
        country Germany = new country(26, 4, "Yes");
        country Austria = new country(28, 1, "Yes");
        country Italy = new country(17, 8, "Yes");
        country Russia = new country(23, 3, "No");
        ArrayList<country> countries = new ArrayList<country>();
        countries.add(Turkey);
    }
}
```

---

*Note*:  The proper convention is to capitalize `Class` names, and have variable names lowercase.

This will require you to change your `Class` name in your code - see below.

```
class Country  {
    private int mland, mwaters; //mtotalborders;
    private String mcenter;

    Country(int earth, int aqua, String yn)  {
        ......
```

Also anytime you reference the `Class` name.  For example.

```
Country turkey = new Country(16, 7, "No");
```

Comment: In Processing, these should actually probably be in a `setup` method, not a main function.

Comment: As addition: you can also put the `countries.add` in an initializer block, if you want them to be added at start.

Comment: @JakeKing Given the nature of the question I'm operating under the assumption that this is an intro hw exercise so giving the basics here.

Answer (score 1):

Lufval, you're trying to write code outside of a class definition.  Global variable declarations are OK, executable statements are not.

Comment: Java doesn't have global variables outside of classes. I think you mean trying to write code outside of a method.